# Amazon EC2 Websokets No Response

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have my client side(html) websocket running on django hosted on Apache on Amazon EC2 and I have my server side(python) websocket on Amazon EC2 (running it as python server.py and listening to a particular port). When I tried to connect my client with server I'm not getting any kind of response from the server. I have made my EC2 security policy to allow any inbound connections(0.0.0.0/0).

But when I do the same process on my local machine (running on local host) everything works without any issue. It would be of great help if anyone could help me on this. Thanks

Comment: You need to debug the TCP connection with standard tools first in order to see if the firewall rules are still an issue.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke
I have resolved the issue, but now its not working over https